# Akka Actor on server not returning an ActorIdentity response to an Identify message

Tags: scala, akka, actor, remote-actors, akka-remote-actor

So I have this segment of code

```
def receive = identifying

def identifying: Actor.Receive = {
    case ActorIdentity(`path`, Some(actor)) =>
      context.watch(actor)
      context.become(active(actor))
      logger.info(s"Identifying actor: $path")
    case ActorIdentity(`path`, None) => 
      logger.info(s"Remote actor not available: $path")
    case ReceiveTimeout => 
      sendIdentifyRequest()
    case _ =>
      logger.info("Not ready yet")
  }
```

However, when I send the identify message (which is the right path) it doesn't get an ActorIdentity, it just prints "not ready yet".

When I run the server locally everything works fine. So I'm really confused as to why the server is working as intended.

Comment: Why are you referring to the `correlationId` as `path`? Also, why are you quoting it in backticks?

Comment: Change your `case _ =>` to `case other =>` and then print `other` in the log message to see what is falling through your match statements. I agree with the above comment that the back ticks might be causing the issue.

Comment: In scala backticks are used to name code. I think your backticked path is interpreted as the path() function of the actor, thus your code matches on it.